# Ionic zooming="true" does not resets the page zoom

Tags: ionic-framework, dialog, zooming, reset

I have modal for displaying Attachments.
When I display one image in modal and pinch zoom , close the modal and click on second image, 2nd image is already zoomed.

How to stop this from happening?

```
<script id="modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view>
    <div class="bar bar-header" class="ng-cloak">
      <button class="button button-clear ion-ios-arrow-left fontSize25" ng-click="closeModal()"></button>
      <h1 class="title customeHeared white-color">Attachment</h1>
    </div>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" delegate-handle="zoom-pane" class="zoom-pane" min-zoom="1">
        <img ng-src="{{imagePath}}" style="width: 100%;padding: 20%;"/>
        </video>
      </ion-scroll>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

Comment: can u give an example with producing this issue

Comment: Just create an Ionic project, take two images and write script so that clicked image will open in modal like above. I am sure it will produce issue for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any solution for this, Closing this now.

If anyone comes here and finds it with an answer please let me know with a comment.